# CSS Navigation images wont stop stacking

Tags: css, navigation, rollover

This is my first time using this site, I am stuck trying to make some rollover navigation. All of the images will do the hover over effect but they are stacking on top of each other instead of next to each other. How do I get them to layout horizontally instead of vertically?

My code is below.

### CSS:

```
html, body{margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: #c0c0c0;}
p{width:900px; position: relative; left: 30px;}
h2{width:900px; position: relative; left: 30px;}
.container{width:960px; margin: auto;}  

.header{height: 124px;}                     
.navigation{height: 59px; width: 960px;}

.navigation1{
        display: block;
    width: 136px;
    height: 59px;
        background-image: url('http://fakehost:8888/TheWorksPlumbing/images/navigationImages/nav_01.jpg');
    background-position:0px -59px;
        text-indent: -99999px;
}
.navigation1:hover{background-position:0px 0px;}

.navigation2{
        display: block;
        width: 138px;
    height: 59px;
        background-image: url('http://fakehost:8888/TheWorksPlumbing/images/navigationImages/nav_02.jpg');
    background-position:0px -59px;
        text-indent: -99999px;
}
.navigation2:hover{background-position: 0 0;}

.navigation3{
        display: block;
        width: 170px;
    height: 59px;
        background-image: url('http://fakehost:8888/TheWorksPlumbing/images/navigationImages/nav_03.jpg');
    background-position:0px -59px;
        text-indent: -99999px;
}
.navigation3:hover{background-position: 0 0;}

.navigation4{
        display: block;
        width: 138px;
    height: 59px;
        background-image: url('http://fakehost:8888/TheWorksPlumbing/images/navigationImages/nav_04.jpg');
    background-position:0px -59px;
        text-indent: -99999px;
}
.navigation4:hover{background-position: 0 0;}

.navigation5{
        display: block;
        width: 168px;
    height: 59px;
        background-image: url('http://fakehost:8888/TheWorksPlumbing/images/navigationImages/nav_05.jpg');
    background-position:0px -59px;
        text-indent: -99999px;
}
.navigation5:hover{background-position: 0 0;}

.navigation6{       
        display: block;
        width: 210px;
    height: 59px;
        background-image: url('http://fakehost:8888/TheWorksPlumbing/images/navigationImages/nav_06.jpg');
    background-position:0px -59px;
        text-indent: -99999px;
}
.navigation6:hover{background-position: 0 0;}

.mainAd{height: 271px;}                     
.mainbody{background-color: white;}
.map{position: relative; left: 30px;}
.footer{height: 197px;}
```

### HTML:

```
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header"><img src="http://localhost:8888/TheWorksPlumbing/images/Layout_01.jpg"></div>
             <div class="navigation" >
                 <div class="navigation1"><a href="home">Home</a></div>
                 <div class="navigation2"><a href="about">About</a></div>
                 <div class="navigation3"><a href="services">Services</a></div>
                 <div class="navigation4"><a href="rates">Rates</a></div>
                 <div class="navigation5"><a href="specials">Specials</a></div>
                 <div class="navigation6"><a href="contact">Contact</a></div>
             </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float: left;
```

on each of your navigation elements will make them horizontal.

Although I think your code is overly complicated. Maybe try using a list and condensing your common styles under

```
ul.navigation li {
     float: left
     .....
}
```

Also, you will likely need to add overflow: hidden to the parent element so that it wraps around the floated list items of your navigation.

```
ul.navigation {
    width: 960px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Adding float left worked beautifully. Thank you!!!! I will also take your other suggestions to reduce code in the future. Thanks again!

Comment: Also something to note on this answer is to move the <a> tags outside of the <div> tags otherwise the images wont be clickable. Just incase someone in the future is having a similar issue!

Answer (score 0):

add this css:

```
.navigation div {
    float: left;
}
```